# Can you transfer some of your questions to your second account?

Tags: support, multiple-accounts

I'm contemplating different accounts for each subfield of a subject, to streamline organization.

Imagine that I prefer this account to focus on antinatalism at Philosophy SE. If I make a new one for questions on euthanasia at Philosophy SE, how can I transfer some questions on my account (the euthanasia ones) to the new account?

Comment: Why the downvotes? Jeez.

Comment: Consider the downvotes as "You shouldn't do it", i.e. people disagree with the idea of doing what you ask for, regardless if it's possible or not.

Comment: Imagine people being able to transfer bad questions to a dump account, and keep asking more of them.  Simple way to evade a question ban, if this could be done.

Comment: @fbueckert Oh! I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No You can't. Under most circumstances you cannot selectively change ownership of a post.

In *theory* you could merge accounts but not selectively split off accounts. The *one* situation where attribution to a question is changed is when there's an incorrect merge (which happened *once*), or some *serious* account messups (but that rarely happens and was good fun).

I suspect this literally would involve a member of staff poking around and editing posts *in the database*, and would probably be more trouble than its worth.